# Ajax - How to use a returned array in a success function this codes

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I use web services, i try this code. i want to select and show my php page , select 1.string or 2.string

**ajax.php**

```
$bb=json_decode($result,true);
$a= strlen($bb[$user_id]['1']);

if ($a!=0)
{
    $this->data[$bb];

    echo "<br>User ID===> ".$bb[$user_id]['1'];
    echo "<br>name===> ".$bb[$user_id]['2'];
    echo "<br>surname===> ".$bb[$user_id]['3'];
    echo "<br>etc..===> ".$bb[$user_id]['4'];
}
```

**x.php** Js codes

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:{user:user,user_id:user_id},
    url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello');?>',
    success: function(result){
        $('#htmlname').html(result); 
    }
}); 
});
});
```

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question.  What do you want?  What goes wrong?

Comment: your Javascript code sample as posted does not compile. Please check before you post in future.

Comment: anyway, as mentioned, what problem are you facing? You haven't mentioned an error message or description of anything which fails.

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: i want to select and show ,result 1.or 2. string

Comment: What does "select and show ,result 1.or 2. string" mean?? Define what you mean by "1. string". Give an example if it's easier. If we understand an example of your desired output it will be a lot quicker to solve. Also, your JavaScript code still has syntax errors. Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: forexample;  "<br>User ID===> ".$bb[$user_id]['1']; select and output User ID===> 2354668 , i see all but i cant select array1 or 1.string i cant explain sory:/

Comment: you want the javascript to select just this part? It can't because to the script your response is just all one big HTML string. So you need to return a JSON array, and then on the client-side select just that one array element.

Answer (score 0):

Return the array as JSON. To do this, set the `dataType` to JSON in your ajax call: 
`dataType: "json"`

You can then access each element of the array in the success callback:

```
success: function (result) {
        var item1 = result[0];
        var item3 = result[2];
    }
```

Comment: not working. $.ajax({
                                type:'post',
                                data:{user_profil:user_profil,user_id:user_id},
                                dataType: "json",
                                url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello');?>',
                                success: function(result){
                                    $('#user_name55').html(result[2]);

Comment: this answer is incomplete. You'd have to show how to change the server-side code as well, because at the moment the server-side returns a HTML string, not a JSON array.